# SharePoint get the full URL of the current page in code behind

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In SharePoint how do you get the url of the page you are on from the code behind?
e.g. with the blah.aspx page included...

SPContext.Current.Web.Url gives http://vm/en/

I need it with http://vm/en/Pages/blah.aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can still get the HttpContext and then use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

SPContext.Current.Web is the SPWeb surrounding the page you're on, and thus its URL is the URL of the Web, not the page.

Comment: Just to be clear, the full parameter to use is System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url

Comment: Well yes, the class HTTPContext is in the System.Web namespace

Comment: Just be carefull if you are doing that with ManagedPaths and /_layouts/ application pages. ex./sites/1/_layouts/page.aspx will be /_layouts/page.aspx

Comment: Just want to stress that last comment (on _layouts). Just got caught with it myself. HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl will give you the true URL (what you see in the browser address bar) but won't have protocol, host or port. Must be a Server.Transfer or something in there.

Answer (score 9):

Try: [SPContext.Current.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.file.aspx).[Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.url.aspx)

You could also use [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx).[Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try : SPContext.Current.Web.Url +"/"+ SPContext.Current.File.Url

Answer (score 1):

This should return what you require SPContext.Current.ListItemServerRelativeUrl

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me, for pages under _layouts and also for 'normal' pages under the site:

```
        string thisPageUrl;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("_layouts"))
        {
            thisPageUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + context.Request.Path; //note: cannot rely on Request.Url to be correct !
        }
        else
        {
            thisPageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: This will exclude possible query string.

Answer (score 1):

I use the workaround which covers _layouts cases

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds real URL considering layouts pages.
/// </summary>
private Uri CurrentUrl
{
    get
    {
        return Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("_layouts")
            ? new Uri(
                SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetResponseUri(
                    SPContext.Current.Site.Zone).ToString().TrimEnd('/')
                + Request.RawUrl) 
            : Request.Url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Path);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string PageTitle=SPContext.Current.File.Title
```