# How to get the original url before redirection in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Basically what I need is the reverse thing of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544268/sharepoint-get-the-full-url-of-the-current-page-in-code-behind/1544304):

Namely, if a user inputs "http://SP2013/my" in the browser, it will redirect to "http://SP2013/my/default.aspx". I need the url before the redirection happens (http://SP2013/my). i.e., I need a way to distinguish these 2 cases:

- case 1. User inputs "http://SP2013/my" in the browser;
- case 2. User clicks the link "http://SP2013/my/default.aspx" in the page.

What I have is the Page object, HostSite, HostWeb, PersonalSite, PersonalWeb object, etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For case 2: If a user clicks a link to SP2013/my **or** SP2013/my/default.aspx, then `document.referrer` returns the url of the page the user clicked a link on.

There doesn't seem to be a way to explicitly answer for case 1, at least not with JavaScript. However, if `document.referrer` returns an empty string, then the user did not click a link. But there is no way to tell whether they entered SP2013/my or SP2013/my/default.aspx into the browser, or what page they were previously on.